# Problem on differential inclusion

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

For a differential inclusion $x'(t)\in h(x(t))$, is there any condition (of course, I don't want the map to be single-valued) under which we can say that for any trajectory $x(.)$ satisfying the differential inclusion there exist a continuous function $F_{x(.)}(.)$ (i.e. depending on the trajectory x(.)) s.t. $F_{x(.)}(x) \in h(x)$ and $x'(t) = F_{x(.)}(x(t))$.

I am aware of continuous selection theorems for set-valued maps, but have not seen anything like above.

Comment: I can't say that I know much about the subject, but have you looked in the book [_Differential Inclusions_](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-69512-4) by Aubin & Cellina (1984)?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine: Yes, but did not get much.

Answer (score 2):

There are such results. For example, if $-h$ is  a maximal monotone operator  on a Hilbert space $H$

$$ A: D(A)\subset H\to 2^H, $$

where $2^H$  denotes  the  collection of subsets of $H$, then the differential inclusion

$$ x'(t)+A x(t)\ni 0,\;\;x(0)=x_0, \;\;t>0, $$

has a unique (appropriately defined)  solution. Moreover,

$$x'(t)+A^0 x(t) =0 $$

for almost all $t$, where  $A^0 x(t)$ denotes the point in the closed convex set $A x(t)$ closest to the origin, i.e., the shortest vector in $A x(t)$. For details I refer to Theorem 3.1 in H. Brezis'  book

> **Operateurs maximaux monotone et semi-groupes de contractions dans les espaces de Hilbert**, North-Holland Publishing Co. 1973.